# Make PHP mail form

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I've an HTML contact form and I want to use it in my footer, but I don't know how to do it!!

Here is my form:

```
<div class="footer-right">

<p>Contact Us</p>

<form action="#" method="post">

<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<button>Send</button>

</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` tag will not submit the form. You should change it to: `<button type="submit">Send</button>`

For handling the form you could add something like this in the beginning of your file::

```
<?
//Mail sending function
$subject = "Web Form";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$to = "youremail@example.com";

//data
$msg = $_POST['message'];       

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;

mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged it as PHP, this answer will get you started.

1. Change:

   ```
   <button>Send</button>
   ```

   to:

   ```
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
   ```
2. Change:

   ```
   <form action="#" method="post">
   ```

   to:

   ```
   <form action="mailer.php" method="post">
   ```
3. Create a file named `mailer.php` and place it in the same folder as the filename of the document you presented, and in that file, add the following contents:

   ```
   <?php
   $recipient="receipient@example.com";
   $subject="new message from ".$_POST['email']." - contact form";
   $message=$_POST['message'];
   mail($recipient, $subject, $message);
   ?>
   <p>Your message has been sent.</p>
   ```

Note that you should add custom HTML between the last two lines of the above code or your HTML won't validate with W3C standards.

Comment: thanks @mike this worked but only has two issue, 1- i need to get wordpress site email directly (no want edit email manually in mailer.php) 2- the email sender is base on website hosting service! can give the name of website into it?

Comment: If the destination email is dynamic without a valid reason (such as user forgetting a password), then you're asking for your website to be a source of email spam. and what do you mean by based on website hosting service? by title of website?

Comment: no my mean is like wordpress has <?php the_title(); ?> and will get the title of post so maybe has some code like that to get website email automatic. and about hosting email is like this: u23t67534663@hostinger.com the email will send like this.